# When I import mobile numbers from CSV file to database, the numbers are stored in 9.78E+12 format. How to store in actual number?

Tags: php, codeigniter

which contains contact numbers in "**9.77985E+12**" format. I have to save the actual contact numbers in mysql database in this format "**9779849561769**". Excel automatically converts the number into "**9.77985E+12**" format. I need to convert "**9.77985E+12**" format into "**9779849561769**" format using PHP. How can I do this?

I used a third party library but it saves in "**9.77985E+12**" format.

Comment: In general, large numbers aren't ___stored___ in that format, they're ___displayed___ in that format.... and that only by default. Use [sprint()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to change the display format..... note that floating point numbers may lose a degree of precision when they are stored though

Comment: But mobile phone numbers should not be treated as numbers, they should be treated as strings, and saved in a varchar() rather than an int or float datatype

Comment: Thanks for you reply Mark but when i change the format to text, it displays "9.77985E+12" format [link](http://oi57.tinypic.com/2vcj194.jpg) @MarkBaker

Comment: What do you mean `when i change the format to text`... do you mean you've modified your database structure? Do you mean you've changed something in your PHP code? Simply changing a value in an Excel spreadsheet won't automagically change anything in your database, and without knowing how this third party library you've mention works, how can we even guess?

Comment: Hi mark thank you for the answer. The problem occured when i save numbers in CSV format from microsoft excel, it loses some degree of precision. This happened while saving the file from my computer only. I tried saving the file from another computer, it worked. I don't know what happened to my excel software. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Look at your csv file in a text editor, and see what's actually stored there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem occured when i saved numbers in CSV format from microsoft excel, it loses some degree of precision. This happened while saving the file from my computer only. I tried saving the file from another computer, it worked. I don't know what happened to my excel software.

Answer (score 0):

The data 9.77985E+12 is a float. It's a not usually a good idea to convert from a floated value to a full value when you need the exact value as you can lose precision from the initial.

You should be able to set the formatting of the cells in excel to 'text' instead of 'integer', which will fix the problem in excel.

Otherwise try this in your PHP to convert it

```
echo number_format($float,10,'.','');
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply Harlan and Mark but when i change the format to text, it displays  "**9.77985E+12**" format  [link](http://oi57.tinypic.com/2vcj194.jpg) @Mark Baker

Answer (score 0):

> if this problems comes for a javascript user when exporting a csv in
> excel format, can use below method. that will solve the problem.

```js
   let mobile = +941231234123
   let mobileForCsv = mobile + '\t';
    
   console.log(mobileForCsv) // +941231234123
```